Facing issue while connecting my react native project with call logs
While trying to connect and fetch details of call logs using react-native-call-logs pacakage, It is not working properly getting blank page. I am expecting popup window which will ask user to allow call logs access. here I am sharing my react native code.
AndroidMenifest.xml


<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.rn_login_signup">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>


MainApplication.java
package com.callogs;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import com.facebook.react.PackageList;
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.List;
import com.wscodelabs.callLogs.CallLogPackage;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost =
      new ReactNativeHost(this) {
        @Override
        public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
          return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
        }

        @Override
        protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
          @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
          List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
          // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
          // packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
          new CallLogPackage();
          return packages;
        }

        @Override
        protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
          return "index";
        }
      };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
    initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
  }

  /**
   * Loads Flipper in React Native templates. Call this in the onCreate method with something like
   * initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
   *
   * @param context
   * @param reactInstanceManager
   */
  private static void initializeFlipper(
      Context context, ReactInstanceManager reactInstanceManager) {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
      try {
        /*
         We use reflection here to pick up the class that initializes Flipper,
        since Flipper library is not available in release mode
        */
        Class<?> aClass = Class.forName("com.rn_login_signup.ReactNativeFlipper");
        aClass
            .getMethod("initializeFlipper", Context.class, ReactInstanceManager.class)
            .invoke(null, context, reactInstanceManager);
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
}


CallHistory.js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button, FlatList, PermissionsAndroid, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import CallLogs from 'react-native-call-log';

const CallHistory = () => {
  const [callLogs, setCallLogs] = useState([]);
  const [permissionGranted, setPermissionGranted] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    requestCallLogPermission();
  }, []);

  const requestCallLogPermission = async () => {
    try {
      const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_CALL_LOG,
        {
          title: 'Call Log Permission',
          message: 'This app requires access to your call logs.',
          buttonNeutral: 'Ask Me Later',
          buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
          buttonPositive: 'OK',
        }
      );

      if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
        setPermissionGranted(true);
        loadCallLogs();
      } else {
        console.log('Call Log permission denied');
        setPermissionGranted(false);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };

  const loadCallLogs = async () => {
    try {
      const logs = await CallLogs.load(5);
      setCallLogs(logs);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>Call Log Example</Text>
      {permissionGranted ? (
        <FlatList
          data={callLogs}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.timestamp.toString()}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <View style={styles.logItem}>
              <Text style={styles.logText}>Number: {item.phoneNumber}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.logText}>Type: {item.type}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.logText}>Date: {new Date(parseInt(item.timestamp)).toLocaleString()}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.logText}>Duration: {item.duration}s</Text>
            </View>
          )}
        />
      ) : (
        <Button title="Request Call Log Permission" onPress={requestCallLogPermission} />
      )}
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    padding: 20,
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 24,
    textAlign: 'center',
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
  logItem: {
    padding: 10,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderBottomColor: '#ccc',
  },
  logText: {
    fontSize: 16,
  },
});

export default CallHistory;


if anything else required please let me know
While trying to connect and fetch details of call logs using react-native-call-logs pacakage, It is not working properly getting blank page. I am expecting popup window which will ask user to allow call logs access. here I am sharing my react native code.

This question is similar to: Android problems with READ_CALL_LOG permission. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
